# parse html table and change every "i" values <td> color

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

Okay, i have a table being generated by havij and have been putting it all together over a couple of days into one HTML file.

Havij colors its rows like so

```
LIGHTORANGE
WHITE
LIGHTORANGE
WHITE
```

After I put the tables together I am getting a ruined pattern

```
LIGHTORANGE
LIGHTORANGE
WHITE
LIGHTORANGE
etc...
```

I wish to scan through this html file and reassign the pattern(fix it)(for visual purposes)

Here is an example using a similar form:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w6dy/)

As you can see, "Joe" is orange when he and every person under him should be the switched in color.

What is the best way of doing this? I don't want to do it as a .exe. Maybe a good solution would be to do it in php

Here is my pseudo code:

```
1. Read the file and be ready to parse it

2. Loop to like 1000, each of the i values from that loop will search for the value last matched in a <td>

3. Per i, change the color in the td attribute of even numbers to orange

4. Output code as a .html file or whatever.
```

Can anyone figure out a working code for this? Any other suggestions to make this faster/easier?

Finally, I cannot manually change it because I currently have 20,000 rows.

Edit : Javascript solution would actually be better

Comment: Could you provide us more about the ruined pattern and pattern you would want?

Comment: like what? Thats all there is to it

Comment: Use CSS selector `:nth-child` and it should work fine, no need to hardcode the color every cell.

Comment: Could you give a working example?

Comment: Try reading here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Also, before I am able to use this css selector, I would need to remove the hard coded colors.

Comment: Easier solution?, You can do all this with css pseudo selectors `tr:nth-of-type(even){background: #DC883D;}` http://jsfiddle.net/KXC8X/1/

Comment: thank you! now i just need to remove all attributes from the td's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the hard-coded attributes from the TDs with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('table tr:not(:first-child) td');
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].bgColor = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use CSS to assign the colors automatically.

The `:not(:first-child)` part of the selector skips over the header row. If you want to remove their attributes as well, and do it with CSS, you can remove that.

Comment: i think the best solution is simply to use notepad++'s replace all.

Comment: I will choose your answer as correct anyways :)(Can't believe i didn't think about it earlier... :P)